# Extends() Method not workin in livewire

Tags: laravel

[Whenever i Try to Extend My livewire component with admin Layout Using Extend or layout Method it Gives me Undefined Method Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzSRa.png)

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image

Comment: Is there actually an error in your app when you try it? This looks like VSCode just isn't properly understanding the class structure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.